# How to fix delay between variable in html and controller in angular 4?

Tags: html, angular

I have a common mistake in angular 4 or 2, it is when I initialize a variable in subscribe it has delay. The problem is when I use that variable in html as *ngIf probably it first render that variable in html and at that time errors it is undefined. What is the best solution except setTimeout for this delay?

this is my html:

```
<a *ngIf="currentUser.type==0" class="tooltip-icon menu-navbar-item" (click)="goListProperty()">
```

and this is my component:

```
import {Component, OnInit, OnChanges, EventEmitter, Output, Input, 
ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {AuthenticationService} from "../../services/authentication.service";
import {LoginService} from "../../services/login-service.service";
import {SignUpService} from "../../services/signup-service.service";
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
@Component({
 selector: 'header-component',
 templateUrl: './header.component.html',
 })
 export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
 private subscription: Subscription;
 menu: boolean;
 index: number;
 menuButton: number;
 user: any;
 isOpen = false;
 currentUser: any;
 loading: boolean;

 constructor(private authentication: AuthenticationService, private 
 signUpService: SignUpService,
          private loginService: LoginService, private router: Router) {
 this.user = AuthenticationService.check();
  }

ngOnInit() {
if (this.user) {
  this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
  console.log(this.currentUser.type);
  this.subscription = this.authentication.notifyObservable$.subscribe(res => 
{
    this.currentUser = res;
    console.log(this.currentUser.type);
  });
}
this.subscription = this.loginService.notifyUserLoginObservable$.subscribe((res) => {
  console.log(res);
  this.user = res;
});
this.index = 1;
}
```

thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 1):

you can set value by default.
for example

```
currentUser: any = [];
```

and your html shloud like

```
<div *ngIf="currentUser.lenth > 0">
<a *ngIf="currentUser.type==0" class="tooltip-icon menu-navbar-item"(click)="goListProperty()">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a *ngIf="currentUser && currentUser.type==0" class="tooltip-icon menu-navbar-
    item" (click)="goListProperty()">
```

here will check if current user is define or not and if not will not check for currentUser.type which prevent error

Answer (score 1):

You can use the null-safe operator in the HTML file like so:

```
<a *ngIf="currentUser?.type==0" class="tooltip-icon menu-navbar-item" (click)="goListProperty()">
```

That way, if currentUser is null or undefined, it will not throw an error.

You can read more about this operator at https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths

Answer (score 0):

put all the code of the ngOnInit in the constructor too, in that way when the page loads for the first time all the variable will have the value and will display in the html.